# Understanding the mechanics of heat transfer and temperature difference affecting air flow

Tags: thermodynamics

So, I understand the thinking that cold air being more dense than hot air results in the sinking of the cold, rising of the hot, and this explains airflow. So what happens when I open a window in winter. Immediately there's a line of warn air inside,cold air outside, so without gravity effects, how does the cold air move sideways? Or does it fall at a bit of an angle down into the opening...but as the previous answers indicates, the warm air has to leave to replace the cold air....so why don't I feel warm air rushing out? And also, warmer air has more energy, i.e. the molecules are moving faster, so in a closed container, that should result in higher pressure, this escaping out the window at seemingly a faster rate than low pressure cold air coming in. So is it a combination of cold air falling into the opening having more mass to the smaller amount of warm air inside that over powers the system and makes it feel like cold air only rushing in? And finally, what makes no sense...how the molecules of warm air way inthe corner away from the window and up at the ceiling, "know" without interaction with the cold air yet, that outside is where it's "supposed" to head? If the warm molecules have more energy and are bouncing all around faster, how does the less energetic cold air effect the high energy area? And how does a colder air molecule 30;feet away "know" to "fall" towards warmer areas?

Comment: Please narrow your posting to one primary concern. At this point, you are asking questions that demand an appreciation of transport (sideways moving air), statistics (air molecules at one location "knowing" where they are to go), and gas law behavior (relationship between temperature, pressure, and density).